# Automate UML Diagram Update in Confluence

Tags: uml, confluence

I usually use Gliffy to draw UML Diagrams in my Confluence documents but I would like to know if there is a way to generate automatically UML diagrams of a project stored in SVN and put like a link on it in my Confluence document so that it's updated whenerver the project is modified in SVN (mostly java projects).

I know that there are maven plugins to generate UML diagrams (Graphviz, UMLgraphdoc...) but I don't know how to point on those generated diagrams in my Confluence document and where should I store them so that Confluence recognizes them. What free solutions can I use in Confluence ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/index.html) combined with [maven-confluence-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-confluence-plugin/) and [maven-plantuml-plugin](https://github.com/jeluard/maven-plantuml-plugin).

An  article that show you How To do this is [here](http://soulsoftware-bsc.blogspot.it/2014/01/plantuml-maven-enrich-your-projects.html)

Answer (score 1):

plantumlrender macro can include other Confluence macros:
Put in "plantumlrender" macro "HTML include" macro. In "HTML include" make link to external html that contents PlantUML code

```
html body pre 
state "In Progress" as InProgress
pre body html
```